# Can a protocol require conforming types to be a subtype of another type?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-protocols

For example: I'd like to say in a protocol definition that, a class conforming it, needs to also subclass `UIView` or another custom class type `MyClass`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, just define your protocol as:

```
protocol SomeProtocol where Self: MyClass {
    // protocol code here
}
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that this is only valid in Swift 4, not Swift 3.